# Azure Key Vault .NET - Method not found

Tags: c#, azure, encryption, azure-keyvault, always-encrypted

I want to use an Always Encrypted SQL 2016 DB in my .NET app with an Azure Key Vault for storing the encryption keys. I have been following this article so far: 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlsecurity/2015/11/10/using-the-azure-key-vault-key-store-provider-for-always-encrypted/

But I receive an exception when I reach this line of the code provided in the article:

```
SqlColumnEncryptionAzureKeyVaultProvider azureKeyVaultProvider =
new SqlColumnEncryptionAzureKeyVaultProvider(GetToken);
```

The exception is:

```
Additional information: Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClient..ctor(AuthenticationCallback)'.
```

I've checked my references and everythings seems to be in place. The GetToken authentication callback method is also there.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: Please see my answer below for the solution

Answer (score 4):

It seems like the issue with the latest Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault nuget package. Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.AlwaysEncrypted.AzureKeyVaultProvider package has a dependency on Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault v 1.0.0 and if you install the latest version (v 2.0.6) it brakes SqlColumnEncryptionAzureKeyVaultProvider. Downgrade Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault package to v 1.0.0 and you will be fine...

Comment: I tried downgrading but things didn't work out. I ended up using another custom implementation of SqlColumnEncryptionProvider that uses the Azure Key Vault.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue of aspnet/Configuration. See https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/issues/569

Answer (score 0):

Please use [version 2.0.20170208](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.AlwaysEncrypted.AzureKeyVaultProvider/2.0.20170208) or greater of the nuget package, this should resolve your problem.